# Error when trying to connect to IBM MQ in running in container in my test

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

I am trying to run a integration test in my spring boot application.

Test involved sending msg to IBM MQ (Running on local m/c in a container) and the asserting the that the listener get the msg.

My test fails with the error:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
See the linked exception for further information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64]

    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
```

Now I am running the IBM MQ as a container. So its not installed on my Windows.
Due to this setup, as suggested in other solutions I can't set the path for the library.

Any suggestion how to fix this.

Note: The application run without issue and connect to containerized IBM MQ and listen and read msg from the queue.

Comment: Is your application connecting as amq client over the network to the mq server?

Comment: I believe, if you don't tell it otherwise, the JMS client will attempt a local connection and then attempt a client connection. Given that you have said that your application runs without issue, and the error messages says this is normal for a client install, I think that is what is going on. Use a WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE or WMQ_CM_CLIENT

Comment: @JoshMc no, my application is not connecting mq over any network

Comment: @MoragHughson I am new to BM MQ so I am not sure what to do when you say "Use a WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE or WMQ_CM_CLIENT".  Not sure if spring provide this configuration setting.

Comment: Please provide your spring config.

Comment: Sorry typo on my part. I meant: use a WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE **of** WMQ_CM_CLIENT, i.e. `cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);`

Comment: Seems like @sanjaykumar81 is using mqallclient.jar which supports only client connections, not bindings meaning there is no mqjbnd64 library shipped. As Morag suggested you will need try with WMQ_CM_CLIENT mode. I did not understand your statement "Note: The application run without issue and connect to containerized IBM MQ and listen and read msg from the queue." - Can you clarify? Are you trying state your requirement?

Comment: Using client mode does not really mean connection is made over a network, It means application is connecting to a queue manager over a TCP socket. You can connect to a MQ queue manager running on the same machine using client mode.

Comment: @Shashi, I read that last statement as meaning that despite seeing the reported error, the application runs fine. That would also fit with the try local then try client mode of operation which I think is the default.